# Angular 2 - Routing/sharing component across multiple applications

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

We have a business requirement where we want to create multiple apps for deploying each app independently without rebuilding entire patent project. Few of these app should be able to run independently but also should be able to get injected into one Parent app.

Running app independently is not a major concern but we should be able to build each individual app and push the bundle to server. Our parent app should be able to route to these bundles and load the latest build. Angular cli has a way to create multiple apps but how will you route from one app to other as both apps will be in two separate bundles.

We thought of using each app as separate module and inject it into parent app as npm dependency but that will require you to build parent app every time for a small change in any app.

Please let me know if there is any way to achieve this in Angular 2/ Angular CLI/ Webpack.

Comment: You may find this discussion interesting: [https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6510](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6510)

Answer (score 1):

check this bro, forcing webpack to build About 2 apps into separate bundles and then somehow load them when their routes are hit.
https://medium.com/@somebody32/how-to-split-your-apps-by-routes-with-webpack-36b7a8a6231

Comment: Can we achieve this using angular-cli multiple apps concept?

Comment: here is a good example https://yakovfain.com/2017/04/06/angular-cli-multiple-apps-in-the-same-project/ i wish that will help you, the multiple apps concept is new and it's not documented well